# Transaction Scope - ORA-02089

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions

I'm using Transaction Scope in my project to control transactions between several SQL instructions (insert, update, delete).

One of my instruction is call a existent stored procedure in database, but into this procedure there is a commit struction. I can't change it because it's used in others process.

When I execute, I get the error: **ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session**

I'm declaring the transaction as the code bellow:

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (TransactionScope transacao = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
{
    ....
    transacao.complete()
}
```

What can I do to resolve that?

Comment: Does `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` fare any better?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I just find the options: Serializable, RepeatableRead, ReadCommitted, ReadUncommitted, Snapshot, Chaos, Unspecified. Sorry, i was find wrong. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: I changed to RequiresNew and the error continue..ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session

Comment: Try TransactionScopeOption.Suppress

Comment: @tbone It's worked, but the actions were confirmed before transaction.complete. It's as if there is no transaction control... I did a test and cancel transaction before complete, but all my data were changed.

Comment: It can't do both.  You can't say it (c#) has control over transactions, then have a called procedure also control the transaction (via commit).  You can make the procedure autonomous, or I have another way to allow the caller of the procedure control the transaction (requires a small change to the procedure, but it will not affect current users once in place).  Would you like that approach also?

Comment: @tbone, Do you have any example for the solution? I think it's my alternative...